# background color produtes over background image on left and top

Tags: css, background-color, transparent

I have a div 40x40px, border 0, padding 0 with a background-color. on top I have a transparent png 40x40px which has an transparent area inside where the background color is visible through it.
My problem: the background is also slightly visible on top and right of the png like a small border. I want the png covers the whole background so that the background color is only visible through the transparency of the png and not at the two borders at all.
Here's the page: http://goo.gl/pFTcRr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's your image that contains these borders.
Zoom a lot on your picture et you will probably see it :)

Comment: Hi Guillaume, totally right thank you! I found the fault in the graphic application due a missalign to the picelgrid > http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42280/white-border-around-transparent-png-after-illustrator-export